# Understanding 変わってくる

Tags: grammar

> 作戦域に生き残りがいるか否かで、取れる戦術は**変わってくる**。力及ばず敗走したならせめて、その程度の情報だけでも援護に来た仲間に渡さなければ。
>
> 「もういない、我々が最後だ！　他の隊は、……みな、屑鉄どもにやられた」
>
> 『そうですか』
>
> 案じるでも悼むでもない、ごく平淡な、突き放した響きの声だった。
>
> 噂に聞く〝死神〟のパーソナルマークは、首の無い骸骨。 　 では──こいつがあの、エイティシックスの。
>
> 『後退して態勢を整えてください。それまではおれ達が支えます』

86─エイティシックス─Ep.2 ─ラン・スルー・ザ・バトルフロント─〈上〉
安里アサト

How should I understand the bold てくる? It doesn’t seem to indicate a gradual change in this case. Nor does it seem to indicate the change is coming towards the speaker.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is the usage of "coming towards the speaker" in a broad sense.

Semantically, using 変わる here is more or less the same: "depending on ..., the strategy I can take will change".  くる adds the feeling that the condition (whether or not there are survivors) affects the speaker as someone who decides the strategy.

Even if the strategy is decided by someone else, it should be possible to understand くる indicates some sort of "affecting".

---

Examples:

- ボーナスの額によって旅行の行き先は変わってくる Depending on the amount of bonus, the destination of vacation will change.
- 大学にうかるかどうかで彼女の未来は変わってくる　Whether or not she will be admitted to the university will change her future.

Comment: Maybe worthwhile noting another common construction is 違ってくる as in データを追加したら料金も違ってくる if Im using that right